How to use a partition on 2 different OSes on a dual boot system?
I am using a dual boot system with arch and Windows (which is going to be replaced soon) can I access my files on both systems if I create a partition on a RAID array and use that partition as a mount.
I have not tried it yet but just wanted to know if it was possible before going through hassle.

You have to fully shutdown Windows, including disabling Fast Startup in the UEFI firmware (if applicable); provided those two things are done and each OS is fully shutdown prior to booting the other OS for accessing the partition, no issues should arise.

@JW0914 ok but do I just mount it or what to access it from either os

@JagratSingh - You still need to fully shutdown Windows.

You can avoid the pains of having to fully shutdown Windows by running a Linux VM or even better and most likely will meet your Linux needs, WSL.

Windows to Linux
Read-only NTFS access has been stable in Linux for a long time. The critical point is that when mounted read-only Linux doesn't write anything to the drive so it shouldn't be able to mess anything up.
Historically read-write NTFS was "less-stable", however in more current versions of Linux, writing to a single partition (no RAID) is usually considered safe as long as the Windows machine is shutdown cleanly i.e. you didn't cut the power or hibernate the system.
Given you have a mirrored raid (RAID 1) you can probably just pick one of the two drives and mount it READ-ONLY. That will give you access to any files saved in Windows, however you won't be able to write them back.

Linux to Windows
If you have WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) you can just follow one of the guides for mounting linux filesystems into your WSL instance.
Alternatively you can create a partition specifically for sharing files between the OS'es formatted as either NTFS or VFat, that might be on your existing drives (if you can do it so the new partition isn't also RAIDed) or alternatively on a new drive.
Another option is just to buy a NAS this is the solution I use, as it can expose the NAS storage over both NFS and SMB for Linux and Windows respectively. This doesn't need to be super high end if you keep all your files on the windows partition, since you only need to use the NAS for moving files back to Windows.

This will depend on the type of RAID array you create - its certainly not trivial.
I'd imagine if you have hardware RAID this will work OK.
I don't think MDADM raid will work robustly because I don't think Windows has support for it.  If you are happy to risk your data https://github.com/maharmstone/winmd might work for you.
I believe Linux can access Fake RAID devices using dmraid - however I've not tried it.
Of-course, all the above is talking about the disk layer - you still need software to access the filesystem.   There is a reasonable amount of support for Windows filesystems on Linux and some projects to let you read some Linux filesystems (eg ext4) under Windows.  If it were me, I'd use a VFAT filesystem if that works, otherwise NTFS.
